# Best-Practice for adding an empty row to a databound Listbox using Linq2SQL & Winforms

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

what is the most robust method for adding a empty row (to select "nothing") to a ListBox?

Sofar i used:

```
       Dim List = Enumerable.Repeat(New TABLE With {.Text = "", .ID = -1}, 1).AsQueryable().Union(From t In mainctx.TABLEs)
       ddlMangelKategorie.DisplayMember = "Text"
       ddlMangelKategorie.ValueMember = "ID"
       ddlMangelKategorie.DataSource = List.ToList
```

But this has some drawbacks:

- wordy
- must explicit write the Type (TABLE in this case), so i cant wrap this in a function
- have not found an solution, which works with anonymous types

I.e. if I add a

```
   From t In mainctx.TABLEs Select Text=col1, id=col2
```

to the query, this method does not work anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it using `Union` (notice that you don't need `Enumerable.Repeat` nor `AsQueryable`).

```
Dim emptyTable As New TABLE With {.Text = "", .ID = -1}
Dim list = {emptyTable}.Union(mainctx.TABLEs).ToList()
ddlMangelKategorie.DataSource = list
```

With anonymous types:

```
Dim emptyTable = New With {.Text = "", .ID = -1}
Dim databaseTables = From t In mainctx.TABLEs 
                     Select Text = t.col1, ID = t.col2
Dim list = {emptyTable}.Union(databaseTables).ToList()
ddlMangelKategorie.DataSource = list
```

Comment: Okay, a bit better in verbosity, but still not working with anonymous types - which is my main problem here...

Comment: Works with anonymous types too, with a slight change (can't use the As keyword for anonymous types). See my edit.